# Magento 1.9 - 2 store, 1 product - different URL

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, store-view

I had Magento 1.9 website which runs with default store only.

Now I have created 1 more store for USA customers with currency $.

Now the issue is why every product have 2 URLs, different URL for both stores. There is an issue and duplicate content issue with SEO, So I want only 1 URL for both stores.

Ex:
**Product:** XYZ
**Store India URL:** xyz.html with price in INR
**Store USA URL:** xyz.html with price in $

I have used one extension which redirects me to the specific store based on user IP.

Thank you.

Comment: is it using 1 domain for all the stores?

Comment: what is the current url for both store

Comment: Yes, 1 URL for all stores. Actually, there are 2 stores. 1 for specific country says IN store and another store for rest of all countries.